# Boost converter Output Voltage problem

Tags: voltage, current, dc-dc-converter, boost, layout

I'm using this [Boost converter](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/APID/ProductDocuments/DataSheets/MIC2251-High-Efficiency-Low-EMI-Boost-Regulator-DS20006487A.pdf) in a design to boost a lithium battery (3.6V-4.1V) to 5.4V for powering a small camera peripheral that requires a typical draw of 80mA. I expect that the worse case current supplied needs to be about 2x 80mA due to efficiency and the switched voltage boost. I followed the reference design from Figure 5-1 on page 10.

SOT-23 Package.

Original circuit and layout:

[image]

[image]

No load switching frequency:

[image]

Load switching frequency (please refer to graph 2-10 of the DS):

[image]

Also, the switching frequency waveforms are not as similar to the graphs 2-10 of the DS. Approximate switching frequency appears to be 1kHz from the above measurements.
The issue is my output voltage drops significantly when I add load to the output.
Any idea what is impacting the performance or why the output voltage is dropping with the load?

I even modified the R1 and R2 combinations. I changed R1 from 910k to 100k recommended in the datasheet. R2 is 33k and hence the output voltage is 5V. Still no improvement.

The output inductor is Bourns SRN3030HA-100M 10uH with Isat 1.6A
I am planning to change the diode from this [Schottky diode](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/ds30217.pdf) to this [Fast switching diode](https://www.vishay.com/docs/85561/ls4148.pdf).

I've modified the layout below.
[image]

Is the above layout OK?
Apart from the layout perspective or improvement, is there anything I need to do to improve the performance?

Comment: The specification says that the inductor Isat must be 20-30% higher than 1.6A. Try changing that and check if it fixes the issue.

Comment: @sai, thank you for the suggestion. Is my modified layout good enough ?

Comment: @sai, is my switching frequency waveform looking good? I do not see a similar waveform as mentioned in the Figure 2-10 of the datasheet. What do you think?

Comment: Where on the circuit (and how) did you connect your oscilloscope probe? Try using thin lines when displaying copper pour outline. Please ensure that scope shots include the 0 volt reference marker point.

Comment: @Newbie, have you checked the IR drops on all the high current paths? Since loop is out of regulation at high load current, I would suspect that.